# Working with Json RPC in VS 2005 without adding a reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to work with Json RPC in C#, VS 2005 without adding a dll (reference)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for as i know, you can't. There only is [JavaScriptSerializer](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/mref/T_System_Web_Script_Serialization_JavaScriptSerializer.aspx) from MS AJAX wich is compatible with .NET 4